# JavaScript (If statement) to insert image based on a value

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am using AutoMailMerge and I am trying to add a JavaScript to check if a field value is "1"  then insert image in the image field.

```
var f = this.getField("Image1_af_image");
if (f.value == "1")
{
f.buttonImportIcon("C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle1.png");
} else if (f.value == "2") 
{
f.buttonImportIcon("C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle2.png");
}
```

This link contains 3 processed files with this above code with 3 diffrent values for "Image1_af_image".
https://gofile.io/d/qMvnfu

Comment: use template literals instead: ```f.buttonImportIcon(`C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle${f.value}.png`);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked now : )

```
var f = this.getField("Image1_af_image");
var n = this.getField("Number");
if (n.value == "1")
{
f.buttonImportIcon("C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle1.png");
} else if (n.value == "2") 
{
f.buttonImportIcon("C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle2.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help ;)

```js
f.buttonImportIcon("C:/Users/EslamSamy/Desktop/MEWA Project/Files/Circles/Circle"+ f.value+".png");
```